# Teams replacing URL with https://teams.microsoft.com/_ when message sent via webhook

Tags: microsoft-teams, webhooks

I created a Teams webhook whick I'm using to post a message that contains a URL. My message body looks like this:

```
{
    "text": "This is the [BBC](www.bbc.com)"
}
```

When I POST it, the message appears in my Teams channel. BBC appears as a hyperlink however, nothing happens when I click it. If I right click I have the option to `Copy Link` or `Open Link`. Copying it adds https://teams.microsoft.com/_ to my clipboard. Opening it attempts to open https://teams.microsoft.com/_, which doesn't exist.

Why is Teams replacing my URL and how do I stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add `https` to the URL:

```
{
    "text": "This is the [BBC](https://www.bbc.com)"
}
```